# Can I configure the Jackson ObjectMapper to deserialize JSON arrays into mutable collections instead of immutable ones?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson

As the question states, I want the Jackson `ObjectMapper` to deserialize a JSON array into a mutable `List` like `ArrayList`.
Currently, it is deserialized into an `ImmutableList`.
I use Spring Boot and would preferrably configure it via `application.yml`.